# Android Create Custom Menu (and custom res/menu folder, no res/menu folder)

Tags: android, android-layout

Should I create my own custom menu folder in an Android project built in Eclipse? For example I want to create a sort of header that is present on all activities. I know that menus should be defined in XML files found in the res/menu folder, but I don't have a res/menu folder.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple just create the folder named "Menu" and add an XML file name it "menu.xml".
In this file you can create your design.

```
<item android:id="@+id/add"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" />
<item android:id="@+id/compare"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" />
<item android:id="@+id/close"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" />
```

Answer (score -2):

The answer is

"Create a new Android XML file in Eclipse by choosing File → New → Other, and then select 'Android XML File.' Select a resource type of 'Menu,' and save the file as main.xml. Eclipse will automatically create a folder, res/menu, where your menu XML files will be stored."

I found the answer [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/28/get-started-developing-for-android-with-eclipse-reloaded/), hope it helps :)